# Why the extra comma in Array#map output used in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml

Previous posts have mentioned how the `toString()` method that will place commas between every item mapped through, and that this could be remedied by using `join(" ")`.

Below, Attempt 2 adds a comma between the displayed objects whereas Attempt 1 doesn't. Why is this?

And how can Attempt 2 be revised so that its output replicates Attempt 1?

```
var data = [ {"name":"John","age":38}, {"name":"Mary","age":33}]
```

Attempt 1 (works perfectly!):

```
data.map(function(e) {
   display2.innerHTML += "Name: " + e.name + " Age: " + e.age + "<br />";
})
```

Output:

```
Name: John Age: 38
Name: Mary Age: 33
```

Attempt 2 (adds a comma between elements – why?):

```
function getNameAge(e) {
  var nameAge = "Name: " + e.name + " Age: " + e.age + "<br />";
  return nameAge;
}

display2.innerHTML = data.map(getNameAge);
```

Output:

```
Name: John Age: 38
,Name: Mary Age: 33
```

Comment: The first example doesn't make sense as `map`. It's really a `forEach` disguised as `map`. The second example makes sense as `map` but will return an array like it's supposed to, hence the comma. You might want `reduce`.

Comment: the `map` method returns an array `[]` and then you are applying it as a string, and the default Array.toString method puts commas as separators. You really should have something like `data.map(getNameAge).join(' ')`

Comment: `map` returns an Array. `innerHTML` takes a string. So the array is [stringified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString). Use `join`.

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First, have a look at `map` function definition (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp):

> (1) The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element.
>
> (2) The map() method calls the provided function once for each element in an array, in order.

### Now, let's analyze what you are doing in both attempts:

#### Attempt 1:

quote (1): In this attempt you are not doing anything with the `map` call return so we can skip it.

quote (2): For each element in the array the `map` function will call the function you passed as argument:

```
function(e) {
    display2.innerHTML += "Name: " + e.name + " Age: " + e.age + "<br />";
}
```

So for each item on `data` this piece of code will append to the `innerHTML` property of `display2` the string you wrote (`"Name: " + ...`), leaving at the end the expected output:

```
Name: John Age: 38
Name: Mary Age: 33
```

#### Attempt 2

quote (2): For each element in the array the `map` function will call the function you passed as argument:

```
function getNameAge(e) {
    var nameAge = "Name: " + e.name + " Age: " + e.age + "<br />";
    return nameAge;
}
```

So when `map`'s execution finish it will return an array containing the values returned in each call to the `getNameAge` function. In your example `["Name: John Age: 38", "Name: Mary Age: 33"]`.

quote (1): In this attempt you are using the `map` function return because you're assigning it to the `innerHTML` property of `display2`. As `innerHTML` is a string property and `map` returns an `Array`, it needs to be converted to an string (implicitly calling it's `toString` method). The `toString` method of an array will print the array values separated by a comma (See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp) generating the unexpected output:

```
Name: John Age: 38
,Name: Mary Age: 33
```

Answer (score 5):

The first example isn't using `map` [as intended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but rather as a glorified `forEach`. `map` works by applying a function to every item in an array and returning the resulting array, which is ignored in this first case. The intent is that `map`'s callback returns the desired modification for the element rather than producing a side effect on an external variable.

Your second example is an appropriate use of `map` since you assign the returned array to a property. Setting `innerHTML` stringifies the array into a comma-separated string; the comma delimiter is the default for [`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString).

Here's a correct usage of map that [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)s the result array into one string without commas:

```js
const data = [{"name": "John", "age": 38}, {"name": "Mary", "age": 33}];
const display2 = document.getElementById("display2");

display2.innerHTML = data.map(e => `Name: ${e.name} Age: ${e.age}<br>`).join("");
```

```html
<div id="display2"></div>
```

If you prefer to have `<br>`s separating elements rather than appended per line, you can use `.join("<br>")`. However, using a list is more semantically appropriate and offers easier manipulation of the contents of each item (removing the bullets using CSS is typical):

```js
const data = [{"name": "John", "age": 38}, {"name": "Mary", "age": 33}];

const list = data.map(e => `<li>Name: ${e.name} Age: ${e.age}</li>`);
document.body.innerHTML = `<ul>${list.join("")}</ul>`;
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ATTEMPT 2 the js implicit cast array into string (and use comma as default separator). So you can explicite cast array to string before set innerHTML by adding `join('')`:

```
display2.innerHTML = data.map(getNameAge).join('');
```

```js
const data = [ {"name":"John","age":38}, {"name":"Mary","age":33}];
const display2 = document.getElementById("display2");

function getNameAge(e) {
    var nameAge = "Name: " + e.name + " Age: " + e.age + "<br />";
    return nameAge;
}

display2.innerHTML = data.map(getNameAge).join('');
```

```html
<div id="display2"></div>
```